# window.autoInit in Rails using material-components-web and webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, material-components, material-components-web

I'm using Rails 5.1.4 with the code below. I have confirmed that the `material.js` file is being processed and the `material-components-web` module is downloaded and discovered.

Why is `mdc` undefined when calling `window.mdc.autoInit()`?

```
// app/javascript/packs/material.js
import 'material-components-web'

// app/views/layouts/application.html.eeb
<html>
  <head>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'material' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>window.mdc.autoInit();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried

- importing `@material/auto-init` separately.
- Putting the `autoInit` call inside an onload
- Adding a `console.dir(window)`/`console.dir(this)` inside pack file. `this` is not `window` inside the the pack file and the exports aren't being attached to `this`

Answer (score 3):

To make `material-components-web` work with Rails I did

```
// app/javascript/packs/material.js
import * as mdc from 'material-components-web'
// for accessing it as a window object
window.mdc = mdc
```

And then I made sure `window.mdc.autoInit()` was called at the end of the body

Comment: thanks a lot for this, this answer explained the instructions found in the material-web-components-web node module.